# Is making any material into wool transform it into a thermal insulator?

Tags: insulators

This questions originates from the existence of a number of wools made of different materials, such as glass or rock, that are used as thermal insulators for e.g. buildings.

I wanted to ask a more general question about whether texture alone can make something a good insulator but I was not sure it was not too broad.

So, there is steel wool, for example. Although its main use is abrasion, does it provide thermal insulation or not?

My intuition would be that the air trapped into the wool adds insulation but steel is a good conductor.

Any general thoughts here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thermal insularity of these various stems largely from the air contained (trapped) in them. Air is a fairly good thermal insulator.

Especially if the air is contained in cellular structures, such as in expanded polystyrene or expanded polyethylene, because restricting the movement of the air reduces conduction/convection through it.

It helps also helps if the 'matrix' material is a good thermal insulator and that's why steel wool will be a poorer insulator than e.g. glass wool because steel is a good thermal conductor, while glass is not.

Comment: But does the air trapped make the final material a better insulator than what you appropriately call the matrix? And if so, why not just trap air between two plates instead of this complex texture, wool?

Comment: *And if so, why not just trap air between two plates instead of this complex texture, wool?* That would work (and is used) but a cellular/woolly structure works better because the air in the small air pockets is less mobile, thereby greatly restricting **convection** and thus heat transfer.

Comment: Thanks, but is air + matrix a better insulator than the stuff used for the matrix alone? i.e. if there is air trapped in cells of rock wool, does it do a better job than rock alone?

Comment: *i.e. if there is air trapped in cells of rock wool, does it do a better job than rock alone?* Absolutely. That's why we turn rock into rock wool. The cellular/woolly structure is a very good insulator, compared to the 'matrix' material used to make it. Examples: wool, cotton, EPS, EPE, rock wool etc.

Comment: But what is the physical explanation for air trapped to be a better insulator than rock or glass? Does it have to do with density only?

Comment: It's a matter of how gasses flow. In tiny cavities they are **much less mobile** than in bulk cavities. This motion (in the latter case) promotes heat transport (convection), which is of course what you want to avoid  if insulation is what you seek.

Comment: Yes I understood this part. But I don't see why a piece of rock would provide more convection.

Comment: In the case of solid rock (glass, PE, PE etc) the heat transfer mechanism is **conduction**, not convection. And these materials are not great conductors of heat (as opposed to metals e.g.) We probably have to be a little careful not to generalise too much but broadly speaking cellular/woolly materials are much better insulators than the matrices they are made of.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, air limits heat transfer by conduction, but since it transfers heat by convection, cells are used to trap it into small pockets. Does that mean that the ultimate insulator, having neither conduction nor convection would be a vacuum then?

Comment: That is exactly right! Look up 'Dewar flask'.

Comment: Alright I think I got it. And wool must be less expensive and easier to manipulate than vacuum insulation in construction so it is more a financial compromise than the best possible insulation. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome.